# Make a pointer to an address which is stored at another address

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have an unknown address (eg fd010000) stored at a known location (00008108). How do I make a pointer out of the unknown address so I can get the value from that address.

```
memory structure:
   0x00008108: fb00de00
   ...
   0xfb00de00: ????????
with fb00de00 being a placeholder
```

How would I access the `????????`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a double pointer and set it to the known address.

```
int **ptr = (int **)0x00008108;

int val = **ptr; // This will set val to ????????
```

Note that converting between integers and pointers is implementation-dependent, but it's likely to work as intended in any reasonable implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You have the memory address

```
0x00008108
```

you dereference that using * to get the value at that address which is :

```
fb00de00
```

Which you said, is a memory address. So you dereference that, which will give you ?????? your unknown value.

Example:

```
int a = ??????; // (Unknown value)
int * b = &a; // fb00de00
int ** c = &b; // 0x00008108

cout << **c; // prints ?????
**c = 56; // change ????? to 56
```